# Why provisioning my dask yarn workers doesn't work?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataproc, dask-distributed

I'm trying to run a dask yarn_cluster job on dataproc and but i can't.

Dask worker log is giving me this issue:

.skein.sh: line 2: environment/bin/python: No such file or directory

while the packaged environnement i give to my yarn_cluster has python3.8 on it.

any idea ?

Comment: Could you add more details about how you created the cluster and what did you do?

Comment: I would recommend you to create an issue at the [github repository](https://github.com/dask/dask-yarn) adding more details on how you created the cluster, what are you doing currently, and the full log. You can also refer to this [document](https://github.com/dask/dask-yarn/blob/main/docs/source/gcp-dataproc.rst#connecting-to-your-cluster) to see if you are doing something different when creating your cluster.